# Receber todos os dados de uma tabela com apenas uma consulta

Tags: php, api, foreach

estou tentando criar um sistema que use imagens do LastFM. Mas quero mostrar apenas as imagens dos artistas cadastrados no banco. Fiz assim:

1. Fiz uma consulta do banco com condição de que banda_id não fosse nulo.
2. Criei um foreach para pegar os dados.
3. Criei mais um foreach dentro do foreach anterior pegando o nome da banda e setando para receber a imagem da API.

Funciona? Digo que sim,mas está com uma demora monstra e até entendo pelos foreach's e **consultas demasiadas**,mas foi o único jeito de pôr em funcionamento.

Eu queria ver com vocês,se teria alguma forma de **pegar todos os dados sem que eu precise fazer "loop" para pegar os dados.**

Estou aberto a sugestões para melhorar, quase certo que estou fazendo algo errado, então toda ajuda é bem vinda.

```
<?php

    $getPag = (!empty($Link->getLocal()[1]) ? $Link->getLocal()[1] : 0);
    $Pagina = new Pager(HOME . '/bandas/');
    $Pagina->ExePagina($getPag, 12);


    $lerbanda = new Ler;
    $lerbanda->ExeLer("ws_bands", "WHERE band_parent IS NOT NULL ORDER BY band_date DESC LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset", "limit={$Pagina->getLimit()}&offset={$Pagina->getOffset()}");


    if (!$lerbanda->getResult()):
        $Pager->ReturnPage();
        WSErro("Desculpe, não existem bandas cadastradas no momento, favor volte mais tarde!", WS_INFOR);
    else:
            echo'<div class="banda_news">';
            echo'<div class="grid-row">';

            foreach ($lerbanda->getResult() as $banda):
                 echo "<img src=\"";
                 echo LastFMArtwork::getArtwork($banda['band_title'],true, "mega");
                 echo "\">";
            endforeach;

            echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';

    endif;
    $Pagina->ExePaginar("ws_bands", "ORDER BY band_date");
    echo $Pagina->getPagina();

?>
```

---

**Classe da API**

http://jonjones.org.uk/blog/getting-and-displaying-album-artwork-using-last-fm-api-in-php/

Comment: Coloque o seu código para vermos

Comment: Eu dei uma olhada na documentação e não encontrei um método de pegar imagens de várias bandas. Você poderia realizar essa consulta periodicamente, salvando as imagens, como se fosse um cache. Acredito que as imagens não mudam frequentemente